# Is this MySQL multiple table join OK?

Tags: mysql

I have one table `service_contacts`  which can contain `listids` from the `lists` table and `contactids` from the `contacts` table.  `contact_list_relationship` has the relationships between `contacts` and `lists` tables.

I'm trying to pull all the contacts which could be in a `contactid` in `service_contacts`, or in a `listid` (which each list contains `contactids`).

```
SELECT d.* FROM service_contacts a 
LEFT JOIN lists b 
    ON a.calllistid=b.listid
LEFT JOIN contact_list_relationship c 
    ON c.listid=b.listid
INNER JOIN contacts d
    ON d.contactid=c.contactid OR d.contactid=a.contactid
WHERE a.memberid=12345
```

This runs, and pulls the expected results. So far ... I'm just wondering if there might be a better way.

Comment: No, it's fine as long as you have correctly indexed columns or defined FOREIGN KEY constraints (which enforce index creation)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: Should be an answer..?!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Hey nice to see you back here! It looks like someone is contributing a more complete answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the fields you are joining on are indexed / or preferably defined with `FOREIGN KEY` constraints (which enforce indexing) you should be fine.

However MySQL does not always use indexes even if they are available.  To check the indexes are being used you can run an explain on your statement i.e.

```
EXPLAIN 
SELECT d.* FROM service_contacts a 
LEFT JOIN lists b 
    ON a.calllistid=b.listid
LEFT JOIN contact_list_relationship c 
    ON c.listid=b.listid
INNER JOIN contacts d
    ON d.contactid=c.contactid OR d.contactid=a.contactid
WHERE a.memberid=12345;
```

the results will inform you which indexes are being used in the statement.  If the results are not as expected you can force Mysql to use the indexes withby stating 'force key for join *`indexname`* after each reference to a table.